# Swagger Configuration for base url

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have my Spring boot application deployed using the Kubernetes cluster.  I have swagger configured using 
springfox.documentation.*

Now on the swagger page when I use "Try it out" button, and submit an API request the Request Url is formed like https://java:9080/api/customer/order Which should be https://application.domain.com/api/customer/order

The swagger page opens at https://application.domain.com/swagger-ui.html#

Any idea how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the swagger ui to use your server. Look at [this document](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md).

Looks like setting the URL environment variable for the swagger UI should work. For better control, you can get a copy of the dist/index.html page, edit it with your configuration options, and mount it into the swagger container.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is straight forward WRT Kubernetes + SpringBoot.

If it's on kubernetes, Then please try to append your application name in the URL.
Refer application name from deployment.yml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: deployment
metadata:
  name: {app-name}
```

Example:-
[https://application.domain.com/{application-name}/swagger-ui.html](https://application.domain.com/%7Bapplication-name%7D/swagger-ui.html)